# Firebase API Initialization failure Android+Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Any One Please Help me
i am new to android development please help me..

I added a firebase recyclerview and firebaseui after that i am getting this error i don't know what to do

At my module's gradle file, I've added:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0' and 

'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```

Full Gradle files are provided below:

> **Top level gradle file**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
}
}

allprojects {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven()
            {
                url "https://google.com"
            }
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

     delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

> **Module Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pachu.my_notification"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  //noinspection GradleCompatible
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
  core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Sir how can i update google service plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FirebaseUI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies):

As of version 4.2.1, FirebaseUI has the following dependency versions:

```
 Library          Version
 firebase-auth      16.0.5
 play-services-auth 16.0.1
 firebase-database  16.0.3
 firebase-firestore 17.1.1
 firebase-storage   16.0.3
```

Therefore you need to update the `firebase-database` to version `16.0.3` and `firebase-auth` to version `16.0.5`.

Also update the google service plugin to version [`4.2.0`](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)